# WPF Usercontrol XAML Triggers not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, event-triggers

I am making an UserControl with XAML which is a simple border with a Dock Panel inside it. And inside the Dock there is an image and text bellow as properties ( i got that all figured out already).

However i need the Border that contains everything to change color on the MouseEnter event of the DockPanel and change it again to default when the MouseLeave event is triggered.

It compiles just fine. The problem is that when i use it on a normal window the Triggers are not even working and the mouse cursor doesnt change when i hover the DockPanel.

```
<UserControl x:Name="StartBtn" x:Class="NMis.Controls.StartCenterButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="155" d:DesignWidth="155" FontFamily="Open Sans" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" UseLayoutRounding="True" IsHitTestVisible="False">   
        <Border BorderThickness="1.5" Height="155" Width="155" CornerRadius="2">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop x:Name="Grad1"  Color="#FF151515" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop x:Name="Grad2" Color="#E54D9EA9" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <DockPanel x:Name="Condominio_Dock" Margin="5,10,5,5" Cursor="Hand" Background="#FFF" MouseDown="DockPanel_MouseDown">
                <DockPanel.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="Condominio_Dock">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="#5fb357" Storyboard.TargetName="Grad1" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="#FF151515"></ColorAnimation>
                                <ColorAnimation To="#FF151515" Storyboard.TargetName="Grad2" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="#E54D9EA9"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="Condominio_Dock">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation To="#FF151515" Storyboard.TargetName="Grad1" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="#5fb357"></ColorAnimation>
                                <ColorAnimation To="#E54D9EA9" Storyboard.TargetName="Grad2" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" From="#FF151515"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </DockPanel.Triggers>
                <Image UseLayoutRounding="True" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding ElementName=StartBtn, Path=Image}" Height="104" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=StartBtn, Path=Text}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.
Apparently IsHitTestVisible must be true for the DockPanel use Triggers

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this problem is the dock panel doesn't have a brush. Because then its transparent it doesn't get found by the hit test.